# A query range date using Cassandra

Tags: nosql, cassandra

I have tried to do a query range date using this schema:

```
create column family fact_ingreso with comparator = UTF8Type and
key_validation_class=UTF8Type and 
column_metadata =
[{column_name: ing_fecing, validation_class: DateType,index_type:KEYS}];
```

and I insert the data on this way

```
// Date format: "2010-04-01 00:00:00"
// The datos[20] has a date as a String in the above format
SimpleDateFormat formatoFecha = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Date fecha = formatoFecha.parse(datos[20]);
System.out.println(fecha);
Column ing_fecing = new Column(toByteBuffer("ing_fecing"));
ing_fecing.setValue(ByteBufferUtil.bytes(fecha.getTime()));
ing_fecing.setTimestamp(timestamp);
client.insert(toByteBuffer(id_row), parent, ing_fecing, ConsistencyLevel.ONE);
```

so far so well, but when I try to do a query range date using the follow code:

```
get fact_ingreso where ing_fecing>2011-01-12;
```

I got the error "No indexed columns present in index clause with operator EQ"

But if I replace the operator ">" for "=" it works:

```
get fact_ingreso where ing_fecing=2011-01-12;
```

output

```
RowKey: 645
=> (column=ing_fecing, value=2011-01-12 00:00:00-0300, timestamp=1361899176638)
```

I am newbie in the Cassandra database and I really need deploy this feature for my thesis work.
If anyone can help me I really appreciate it.

edit: Cassandra version is 1.2
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Cassandra you have to have at least one value specified using an equals clause; i.e. you can't just specify a range.  An easy way to do this is to write a sentinel column that represents a known value.  For example, you could write a column representing the current month or year, then use that as your equals.  Any value you can know at query time will do the trick.